# In a finally block, can I tell what exception has been thrown?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch-finally

In a finally block, can I tell **what** exception has been thrown?

I understand, that we can verify in a finally block if an exception had been thrown.

Comment: You could have a variable in the same scope as the `try`, and set that to the thrown exception inside the `catch`. I don't think there's a built-in mechanism for this, and it could probably be argued that you're going about the design wrong if you require this. Note that obviously an exception may not have been thrown when you code enters `finally`.

Comment: You shouldn't need to know. At this point you are only concerned with cleaning up. Any exception has already been dealt with.

Comment: "I understand, that we can verify in a finally block if an exception had been thrown." Not without extra work, e.g. keeping a variable which is set either in a catch block or at the end of the try block...

Comment: @JonSkeet, Yes I agree.

Comment: You shouldn't be worried about exceptions in a `finally` block, that's what the `catch` block is for

Comment: What's your need to do this? As others have said, you can deal with the exception in `catch`, and `finally` is for cleaning up any resources, not handling the exception. There should be no need to even consider whether an exception has been thrown in `finally`.

Comment: I am calling a same method, depending on what exception occurred.

So currently, there are 5 exception cases. 
I am thinking of refactoring my code, so that I have a call only in the finally block.

I do understand that the method will be called only once. But coding-wise, I feel writing it in finally block would be better.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @sau123 You can have a single `catch` block that catches multiple types of exceptions.

Comment: As mentioned above, my main attempt is to get rid of the duplicate code.

@Alexander there are two tasks in each catch block, just one of them is common for all. the other task is different depending on which exception is caught.

Comment: @sau123 so exact the common code to a new function.

Answer (score 6):

I can't envision a situation in which this would ever a sensible thing to do, but you can try something like this:

```
class Main {
    public static void throwsException() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception();  
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Exception caughtException = null;

        try {
            throwsException();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            caughtException = e;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            System.out.println(caughtException);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**catch** block and **finally** are 2 different scopes . The exception caught in the **catch** block is not visible to **finally** block. You can use the Alexander answer to print the exception in the finally block.